# Pygame: When certains butons are clicked timer goes down

Tags: python, pygame

I am making an RPG game (this is my first ever game, I started coding 3 months ago) where one element of it is increasing hunger. Basically, the player's "hunger level" increases over time and if this lvl reaches "5" the player dies (pygame.quit()). However, in one building of my game (the store), the player can purchase food items to reduce this hunger lvl. So, with the hunger timer increasing by 1 about every 2 minutes, how can I make it so when the food items are purchased (click of a button) this "hunger lvl" will go down. For example say the player purchases a bag of cheetos (click's the cheeto button) the hunger lvl (timer) will go down by 1 (decrease by 1 minute).

Here is my code for the store building , any help is much appreciated:

```
#Defining the store building on the map
import pygame, sys 

mainClock=pygame.time.Clock()
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()

def draw_text(text, font, color, surface, x, y):
    textobj=font.render(text, 1, color)
    textrect=textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft=(x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)



    def store():
        global click

        font=pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 50,)
        colorC = (238,59,59)
        (widthC, heightC) = (1000, 800)
        screenC = pygame.display.set_mode((widthC, heightC))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Store')
        screenC.fill(colorC)
        draw_text('Inside The Store:', font, (0,0,0), screenC, 20, 20)

        cheetos_button=pygame.Rect(20, 325, 475, 50)            
        buttonC_color=(156,102,31)
        pygame.draw.rect(screenC, (buttonC_color), cheetos_button)
        text=font.render("Hot Cheetos: $50, -1 Hunger", True,(0,0,0))
        screenC.blit(text, (20,325))
        cheetoImg=pygame.image.load("hotcheetos.png")
        x=20
        y=50
        screenC.blit(cheetoImg, (x, y))

        icedtea_button=pygame.Rect(20, 585, 475, 50)           
        buttonC_color=(156,102,31)
        pygame.draw.rect(screenC, (buttonC_color), icedtea_button)
        text=font.render("Iced Tea: $75, -2 Hunger", True,(0,0,0))
        screenC.blit(text, (20,585))
        icedteaImg=pygame.image.load("icedtea.png")
        x=15
        y=380
        screenC.blit(icedteaImg, (x, y))

        pizza_button=pygame.Rect(525, 585, 475, 50)                
        buttonC_color=(156,102,31)
        pygame.draw.rect(screenC, (buttonC_color), pizza_button)
        text=font.render("Pizza Slice: $200, -5 Hunger", True,(0,0,0))
        screenC.blit(text, (525,585))
        cheetoImg=pygame.image.load("pizza.png")
        x=450
        y=75
        screenC.blit(cheetoImg, (x, y))

        font=pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 25,)
        text=font.render("Your Money:", True,(0,0,0))
        screenC.blit(text, (400,20))
        currentM=0
        font=pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 25,)
        text=font.render(str(currentM), True,(0,0,0))
        screenC.blit(text, (510,20))


        #Increasing hunger levels:
        pygame.init()

        # Loop until the user clicks the close button.
        done = False

        # Used to manage how fast the screen updates
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        font2 = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)

        frame_count = 0
        frame_rate = 60
        start_time = 90

        # -------- Main Program Loop -----------
        while not done:
            for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
                    done = True  # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

            #Clearing the screen
            clear_button=pygame.Rect(700, 20, 150, 25)
            colorC=(238,59,59)
            pygame.draw.rect(screenC, (colorC), clear_button)

            # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT
            #--- Timer going up ---
            # Calculate total seconds
            total_seconds = frame_count // frame_rate

            # Divide by 60 to get total minutes
            minutes = total_seconds // 60

            # --- Timer going up ---
            # Calculate total seconds
            hunger_lvl = frame_count // frame_rate

            # Divide by 60 to get total minutes
            minutes = total_seconds // 60

            # Use python string formatting to format in leading zeros
            hunger_lvl = "Hunger Level: {0}".format(minutes)


            #Blit to the screen
            text2 = font2.render(hunger_lvl, True, (0,0,0))
            screenC.blit(text2, [700, 20])


            # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT
            frame_count += 1

            # Limit frames per second
            clock.tick(frame_rate)

            if minutes >= 5:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
            pygame.display.flip()

        # Be IDLE friendly. If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
        # on exit.
        pygame.quit()


        hunger_lvl = "Hunger Level: {0}".format(minutes)
        minutes=0
        done = False

        while not done:
            mx, my=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if cheetos_button.collidepoint((mx, my)):
                        if event.button == 1:  
                            minutes -= 1
                    if icedtea_button.collidepoint((mx, my)):
                        if event.button == 1:  
                            minutes -= 2
                    if pizza_button.collidepoint((mx, my)):
                        if event.button == 1:
                            minutes -= 5

            #Clearing the screen
            font=pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 50,)
            colorC = (238,59,59)
            (widthC, heightC) = (1000, 800)
            screenC = pygame.display.set_mode((widthC, heightC))
            pygame.display.set_caption('Store')
            screenC.fill(colorC)
            draw_text('Inside The Store:', font, (0,0,0), screenC, 20, 20)

            cheetos_button=pygame.Rect(20, 325, 475, 50)            
            buttonC_color=(156,102,31)
            pygame.draw.rect(screenC, (buttonC_color), cheetos_button)
            text=font.render("Hot Cheetos: $50, -1 Hunger", True,(0,0,0))
            screenC.blit(text, (20,325))
            cheetoImg=pygame.image.load("hotcheetos.png")
            x=20
            y=50
            screenC.blit(cheetoImg, (x, y))

            icedtea_button=pygame.Rect(20, 585, 475, 50)           
            buttonC_color=(156,102,31)
            pygame.draw.rect(screenC, (buttonC_color), icedtea_button)
            text=font.render("Iced Tea: $75, -2 Hunger", True,(0,0,0))
            screenC.blit(text, (20,585))
            icedteaImg=pygame.image.load("icedtea.png")
            x=15
            y=380
            screenC.blit(icedteaImg, (x, y))

            pizza_button=pygame.Rect(525, 585, 475, 50)                
            buttonC_color=(156,102,31)
            pygame.draw.rect(screenC, (buttonC_color), pizza_button)
            text=font.render("Pizza Slice: $200, -5 Hunger", True,(0,0,0))
            screenC.blit(text, (525,585))
            cheetoImg=pygame.image.load("pizza.png")
            x=450
            y=75
            screenC.blit(cheetoImg, (x, y))

            font=pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 25,)
            text=font.render("Your Money:", True,(0,0,0))
            screenC.blit(text, (400,20))
            currentM=0
            font=pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 25,)
            text=font.render(str(currentM), True,(0,0,0))
            screenC.blit(text, (510,20))

            pygame.display.flip()
            mainClock.tick(30)

        pygame.quit()

     store()
```

Comment: The formatting/indenting is all messed up here. It makes it very difficult to look at the code. Your `store()` function is inside the `draw_text()` function, and your main code block (the `pygame.init()` and the main game loop) appears to be inside that. You will need to look at the code included in your question and ensure that it matches your code. The simplest way to include code properly to paste it in and the highlight it all and then click the `{}` button on top of the editing window. You also seem to have extra code after the `pygame.quit()`.

Comment: Oh shoot I didn't realize that the indentation was messed up. Do you think you can help me? I just need to figure out what code to write when a food item button is clicked such that it will descrease the timer (hunger value).

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a bit of re-work.  It's easy to tell because it has basically the same section of code repeated 3 times with only minor differences.  As soon as you start to see this, you should be thinking about moving this code into a function.

You're making these on-screen controls, which are basically a button.  So what is a button?  It's an image, a location, maybe a rectangle to click-in, and some meta-information (the hunger points, name, whatever).  So let's make a class to hold one.  A class (or an "object") is a bunch of data and functions sandwiched together.

```
class Button:
    def __init__( self, image_filename, position, name, food_val, font, colour=(0,0,0), back_colour=(156,102,31) ):
        """ Create a new button """
        self.image        = pygame.image.load( image_filename ).convert()
        self.rect         = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = position
        self.text         = self.font.render( self.name, True, colour, back_colour )
        self.text_pos     = self.text.get_rect()
        self.text.topleft = ( position[0], position[1] + 30 )   # underneath icon
        self.food_val     = food_val
```

And that's it.  We have a class to hold everything that a button needs.  But to use the button, we need to draw it.  So adding a draw function is easy, because everything is already created and knows its position.

```
def draw( self, screen ):
    """ Given a Surface, draw ourselves on it """       
    screen.blit( self.text, self.text_pos )
    screen.blit( self.image, self.rect )
```

Finally a button needs to know when it has been clicked.  The button "knows" its position and size, so we can simply give it a mouse-position, and do a check:

```
def wasClicked( self, mouse_position ):
    """ Given a click co-ordinate, was it inside the image rectangle """
    return self.rect.collidepoint( mouse_position )
```

So how can we use this?

```
button_font = pygame.font.SysFont( 'Comic Sans MS', 50 )

cheetos_button = Button( "cheeze.png", (  20, 50 ), "Pizza: $75", 3,  button_font )
pizza_button   = Button( "pizza.png",  ( 450, 75 ), "Cheese: $50", 6, button_font )
choco_button   = [...]
icetea_button  = [...]

all_buttons = [ cheetos_button, pizza_button, choco_button, icetea_button ]
```

You can see that by using a single class, defining new buttons becomes easy.  You have only one set of code to create, draw and click the button.

So now in your main loop (assuming the buttons are already made):

```
while not done:
    # Process events:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Mouse clicked, check buttons for collision
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            # Loop through all buttons, checking for click-inside
            for butt in all_buttons:
                if ( butt.wasClicked( mouse_pos ) ):         
                    print( "Player Om-nom-noms" )
                    player.hunger -= butt.food_val
                    break  # no need to check further
```

Comment: Thank you for all this. However, I have all the buttons made I just want to make it so when a button is clicked the number of minutes (hunger lvl) decreases.